# Deserialize object is producing double brackets

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, .net, json.net

I have method, where I deserializing JSON message came from AWS Lambda.

Here is the class:

```
public class SendEmailMessage
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public int TemplateId { get; set; }

    public List<string> Attachments { get; set; }
}
```

Here is how I deserialize the message:

```
public async Task ProcessMessageAsync(SQSEvent.SQSMessage message, ILambdaContext context)
{
        try
        {
            var emailRequest = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SendEmailRequest>(message.Body);
            var email = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SendEmailMessage>(emailRequest.Message);              
            await SendEmail(email.From, email.To, email.Subject, email.Attachments, email.Data);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine($"Message processing failed: {e.Message}");
            throw;
        }
}
```

Here is the original message

```
"body": "{ \"Message\":\"{ 'from': 'nemesises@live.com','to': 'suhomlin.eugene93@gmail.com', 'subject' : 'test subject', 'data': {'FirstName': 'Eugene', 'LastName': 'Sukhomlyn'},'attachments': ['https://data.dev.playter.co/client_logos/ff9ec9c7-0e9b-4ce3-88a8-0a31c79d9d4a.jpg']}\"}"
```

All working well, but data is looking like this after deserializing, it's in 2 brackets.

[image]

Here is expanding view, so as I see it's not correct object

[image]

How I can convert it to valid C# object?

Comment: Note that you're seeing a string representation of the object which the debugger has generated for you (possibly using the object's `ToString()` method, but perhaps not) -- it doesn't necessarily correspond to exactly what's there! Expand the `Data` member in the debugger and actually have at what the object type is and what its properties are. Do they look correct?

Comment: The data type of `Data` is just `object` -- so how does json.net know what type of object to put in there? It can't literally create an instance of `object`, as it wouldn't be able to set any properties on it. What it's done instead, by the looks of it, is to assign a value of type [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), which is the best it can do. If you want your `Data` property to have a particular type, then you need to give it that type. For example, maybe you want it to be a `Dictionary<string, object>` or something?

Comment: `Data` is declared as `object`. What type is it after deserialization?

Comment: it must be anonymous object@phuzi

Comment: json.net can't generate a new anonymous object type for you: that's not possible.

Comment: Using Jobject has `{{ }}` stuff too. How I can fix this? @canton7

Comment: What data type do you *want* there? You can't have an anonymous object.